# PyQGIS - Save processing output to temporary file which is discarded when QGIS is closed (on Windows)

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-3

QGIS 3.10.1, Windows 10:

When using the GDAL tool *Clip Vector by Extent* from the processing toolbox and saving the output to a temporary file, the output layer appears in the layer list with a special icon (looks like RAM) and the information: "Temporary layer only! Contents will be discarded after closing QGIS":

[image: Temporary output layer]

Is it possible to create such a tempory layer also on Windows when using the tool in PyQGIS?

On Linux this is possible, just save the output to `/tmp/`.

However on Windows, saving the output to the Windows Temp folder (`.../AppData/local/Temp/`), the created output is not discarded after closing QGIS.

Here is the code I'm using in PyQGIS:

```
clipped_layer = processing.run("gdal:clipvectorbyextent", {'INPUT': id, 'EXTENT': canvasExtent, 'OUTPUT': outputFolder + 'Canvas_Clipper.A_' + map.name() + '.gpkg'})

newLayer = QgsVectorLayer(clipped_layer['OUTPUT'], 'A_' + map.name(), 'ogr')
QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(newLayer, False)
clippedGroup.insertLayer(1, newLayer)
```

Other answers here on gis.stackexchange are suggesting to use `NONE` or `'memory:'` as output parameter, but this gives an error in PyQGIS. Seems like for GDAL tools there is a need to specify an output path.

When using the tool from the processing toolbox in QGIS, the output is saved to a folder which is prefixed `processing_` (see the following screenshot). This folder is discarded when QGIS is closed and I assume this folder is created when starting QGIS (the name of the folder changes for every QGIS session).

Is there a way to use/get the name of this tempory `processing_` folder as output folder from PyQGIS when running the GDAL tool or to create such a folder which is automatically discarded when QGIS is closed?

[image: Clip vector by Extent]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use the special value `QgsProcessing.TEMPORARY_OUTPUT` as the output parameter value, and the rest will all be taken care of for you.

e.g.

```
clipped_layer = processing.run("gdal:clipvectorbyextent", {'INPUT': id, 'EXTENT': canvasExtent, 'OUTPUT': QgsProcessing.TEMPORARY_OUTPUT})['OUTPUT']
```

Comment: Thanks @ndawson, now the ouput is saved like it is done when using the GDAL tool from the processing toolbox (in a `processing_folder_` in another `processing_folder_` in the temp folder) and the RAM icon is also visible. However, these `processing_` folders are not deleted when QGIS is closed - they are only deleted if they are empty. They also still exist after a restart of Windows. I'll accept your answer because I think this a bug in QGIS, similar to this one: https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/issues/28222 What do you think?

Comment: On Linux the `processing_` folder is discarded when QGIS is closed. So this should be a bug on Windows. Opened an issue on GitHub: https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/issues/33641